# Why cat command redirect a new file get executed right away?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, here-document

I want to generate a bash file that could be called later, like this

```
cat <<-SCRIPT >test-$$
        #!/bin/bash
        osType=$(grep -Po '^NAME="\K[^"]*' /etc/os-release)
        if [ "$osType" = ...]
        then
            ...
        fi
        exit
    SCRIPT
```

while I am dubugging, the grep command always get execute right way, why? also try with awk same error

but if I do this

```
cat <<-SCRIPT >test-$$
        #!/bin/bash
        rpm -q somepackage > test-$$
        rm test-$$-lock
        exit
    SCRIPT
```

I don't see the rpm command get executed right way?
Also does test-$$ and test-$$-lock will have the same $$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A here-doc like `<<-SCRIPT` acts like a double-quoted string in that expansions are processed within it. To prevent that, quote the delimiter:

```
$ cat <<EOF
1+1 = $((1+1))
EOF

1+1 = 2
```

vs.

```
$ cat <<'EOF'
1+1 = $((1+1))
EOF

1+1 = $((1+1))
```

---

So, here:

```
cat <<-SCRIPT >test-$$
        ...
        osType=$(grep -Po '^NAME="\K[^"]*' /etc/os-release)
```

The `grep` command is within a command substitution which gets processed because `SCRIPT` is not quoted, so it is executed when the here-doc is used.

Here, on the other hand:

```
cat <<-SCRIPT >test-$$
        #!/bin/bash
        rpm -q somepackage > test-$$
        rm test-$$-lock
        exit
    SCRIPT
```

there's no command substitution, so no commands run. The `rpm -q somepackage` part is just text. However, with an unquoted delimiter, `$$` inside the here-doc would be expanded immediately, to the same value used in the name of the output file. That is, if the current shell's PID is 1234, the `cat` command would create `test-1234` containing the line `rpm -q somepackage > test-1234`.

With a quoted delimiter, the `$$` would be left as-is, and the result would be file called `test-1234` containing `rpm -q somepackage > test-$$`. If you now ran `test-1234` as a script, the `$$` would be expanded then, and *that* shell's PID would be used. It would probably be different from the value used when creating the file.

In any case, the `$$` in `rpm .. > test-$$` and `rm test-$$-lock` would get expanded to the same value.

Comment: Thank you, can you help the follow up?

Comment: @Tiger, all right, does that clarify?

Comment: super! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: +1 for pointing out different behaviors induced by quoting heredoc delimiters.